# Prevent library access

Tags: android, jar

I have a library in my project which I do not trust. I do not want to decompile it and have a look into the code. Is there a way to prevent it form inheriting all the rights in the manifest file (e.g., for example, internet access)?

Comment: ok this means i have to decompile it and look for suspicious imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there  is no way to do it       there  is no way to do it